# All of the Jenkins jobs are disabled on its own

Tags: jenkins

I have been using Jenkins and after a while, all of the jobs are disabled on its own. Jobs can be disabled only by admins and admins did not disable them. This happens quite frequently and I would like to know if there's a way to stop this or at least figure out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Have admins check the system logs for a cause ...?

Comment: Based on the system logs, I am getting `Error while serving http://localhost:8080/job/JobTitle/rssFailed` @IanW

Comment: There has to be something else before that. Check via the OS, not the UI.